# Promises: return then() when action inside it is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I am using React-Redux-Express, and I'm trying to upload an image with `express-fileupload`. Here is my logic for uploading images in my Express server:

In my Express route I do this with Sequelize

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    models.Projects.update(
        {
            title: req.body.title,
            img: req.body.img,
            description: req.body.description,
        },
        {
            returning: true,
            plain: true,
            where: {
                id: req.params.id,
            },
        }
    )
        .then(() => { 
            if (req.files) {
                req.files.imgFile.mv(toRelative(req.body.img), function(err) { 
                    if (err) {
                        throw new Error('Image saving failed');
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        .then(() => { 
            models.Projects.findById(req.params.id).then((result) => {
                return res.send({
                    Project: result,
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return res.send(String(error));
        });
});
```

The problem is that the last `then` is triggered before `req.files.imgFile.mv` method is finished moving the image, so the React input component can't find it in the frontend.

Does anyone know how can I create a promise inside the first `then`, so only when `req.files.imgFile.mv` is finished moving the image the second is triggered?

Thanks!

Comment: i think you are missing a second callback in the `req.files.imgFile.mv(toRelative(req.body.img), function(err) { 
                    if (err) {
                        throw new Error('Image saving failed');
                    }
                });` with the result.

Comment: Put a promise inside the then.

Comment: Have you tried executing the code you are trying to run on the second then inside the callback for the req.files.imgFile.mv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general idea when you have something callback-based rather than Promise-based is to explicitly construct a Promise so it can be used in the larger Promise chain:

```
.then(() => { 
  if (!req.files) return; // resolve immediately if there are no files
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    req.files.imgFile.mv(toRelative(req.body.img), function(err) { 
      if (err) return reject('Image saving failed');
      resolve();
    });
  });
})
```

But, in this case, it would be easier to omit the callback function to force `req.files.imgFile.mv(` returns a `Promise` itself:

```
.then(() => { 
  // if there are files, then the outer Promise chain will wait
  // for the returned Promise to resolve before continuing with the next .then:
  if (req.files) return req.files.imgFile.mv(toRelative(req.body.img));
})
```

Comment: I see now in the  that [github docs](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) that it returns a promise; so is this correct as well?:
`.then(() => {
            if (!req.files) return;

            req.files.imgFile.mv(toRelative(req.body.img)).then(() => {
                return;
            });
        })`

Comment: Ah, so it is, you were originally using it as a callback. Omitting the callback function, you still need to `return` the `Promise` returned by `.mv` for it to be chained properly, as in edit

Comment: And this can be written also like `return req.files ? req.files.imgFile.mv( toRelative(req.body.img) ) : true;`, right?

Comment: You could, but it's unnecessary. If the return value is not a Promise (for example, if *nothing* is returned, defaulting to `undefined`), the next `.then` will run immediately. The returned `true` expression would go unused. `if` is probably better.